# NodeJS/MongoDB Update an Array within an Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, updates

I am attempting to edit an array within an object on my Express/NodeJS application. Below is the data from the collection of Locations:

```
{ _id"56873fc9182b3741059357d0", 
  longitude: 113.83507800000007, 
  latitude: 22.1533884, 
  location: "Hong Kong", 
  name"Hong Kong", 
  __v0, 
 reviews: {review_id: "OBY3iC1IcdIE", comment: null, rating: null }
          {review_id: "3433iC1IcdIY", comment: null, rating: null }
}
```

I'd like to edit one of the reviews (example: review_id:"OBY3iC1IcdIE") but my server side code makes the app crash. My current server side code is:

```
 exports.editReview = function(req, res) { 
    Location.update({ _id: req.params.location_id, reviews.review_id: req.params.review_id }, 
  { $set: { review.comment: req.body.comment, 
 review.rating: req.body.rating }}, function(err, location) { 
      if(err)    
         res.send(err);  
      res.json(location); 
  }); 
 };
```

Comment: { $set: {" reviews.comment": req.body.comment, 
 "review.rating": req.body.rating }}. When ever you need nested fields you need to use double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 exports.editReview = function(req, res) { 
    Location.update({ _id: req.params.location_id, "reviews.review_id": req.params.review_id }, 
  { $set: { "reviews.comment": req.body.comment, 
 "reviews.rating": req.body.rating }}, function(err, location) { 
      if(err)    
         res.send(err);  
      res.json(location); 
  }); 
 };
```

Try this, add double quotes when you need to use nested fields. I am assuming your mongodb setup is fine in your app

Comment: I just added this code and got a Mongo Error with the message "cannot use the part (reviews of reviews.comment) to traverse the element."

Comment: I just fixed the code and it works. With your help, I added $ signs to "reviews.$.comment" and "reviews.$.rating" as per the MongoDb documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say thank you @SumanLama for the assistance. I added the necessary $ signs as per the MongoDB documentation.

```
exports.editReview = function(req, res) { 
  Location.update({ _id: req.params.location_id, "reviews.review_id": req.params.review_id }, 
    { $set: { "reviews.$.comment": req.body.comment, 
       "reviews.$.rating": req.body.rating }}, function(err, location) { 
        if(err)    
          res.send(err);  
        res.json(location); 
 }); 
};
```